# constexpr random

Tags: c++, constexpr

хочу поинтересоваться у обывателей стака об одном очень интересном вопросе. Возможно ли реализовать такую функцию, которая в одно время будет предкомпилированной ( constexpr ) и в то же время будет возвращать случайное значение при вызове. Например:

```
constexpr uint32_t h1 = function( );
constexpr uint32_t h2 = function( );
constexpr uint32_t h3 = function( );
```

И все эти переменные должны иметь разное значение. Как по мне это выглядит противоречиво, а что думаете Вы?

Comment: Но тогда - если такое представить - эта случайность и не случайность вовсе. Тогда уж проще написать дополнительную программку, которая перед компиляцией создает эти случайности в каком-то заголовочном файле...

Comment: нужна 1 функция, а не куча переменных, которые хранят в себе эти случайности.

Comment: Если вы не собираетесь хранить эту "случайность" в переменных `constexpr`, то и `constexpr`-функция вам ни к чему...

Answer (score 4):

Если что то в с++ нельзя решить обычным кодом, тогда нужны шаблоны. Если не справляются шаблоны, тогда нужно доставать самую черную магию - макросы. В с/с++ есть ряд заранее определенных макросов, значение которых "зависит от места". К таким относятся `__TIME__` (время на момент компиляции), `__COUNTER__` (просто счетчик, который увеличивается при каждом обращении), `__LINE__` (номер текущей строки). Учитывая все это, скомбинируем их где то так

```
#define function() (__TIME__[7] * __COUNTER__ * __LINE__) % 17
```

или

```
#define function() (__TIME__[7] + __COUNTER__ * __LINE__) * 100 % 19
```

Даже будучи вызванным в одной строки, скорее всего даст разные результаты (об этом побеспокоится `__COUNTER__`). Так же при разных компиляциях будет разное время, а `__TIME__[7]` возвращает последнюю цифру секунд (как символ) (формат `__TIME__` специфицирован - `hh:mm:ss`).

Можно конечно ещё и `__DATE__` использовать, но оно не так часто меняется. В целом, комбинируем, наслаждаемся.